# Kendo UI - Property Changed MVVM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I seem to be having issues databinding 'calculated' fields with Kendo UI.

I am attempting to do data-binding with several what I will call 'calculated' fields.  I have a grid, several buttons, filters and some sorting on a page that are all using the same datasource, an observable array called 'allItems'.  allItems is populated via a service call and sorted, manipulated and otherwise changed while the user is on the page via buttons.

There are several navigational buttons and several div's that are populated based on information in the previous item, current item and next item in accordance to the current filters and sorts applied.  Those buttons contain information in them that is extracted from the previous, current and next items as they related to the allItems list (ie the objects are actually held in the allItems array and are in fact observable objects).

so in the viewmodel object I have something like this (please excuse short handing):

```
var viewmodel = kendo.observable({
var allItems = observablearray[]

var currentIndex = 1; //or other default value

var changeCurrentItem = function(){
    var self = this;
    //do some stuff
    //stuff might include modification to allItems
    self.set("currentIndex", someNewValue);
}

var previousItem = function(){
    return self.get('allItems')[currentIndex - 1];
}

var currentItem = function(){
    return self.get('allItems')[currentIndex];
}

var nextItem = function(){
    return self.get('allItems')[currentIndex + 1];
});

return viewmodel;
```

The buttons and other info boxes are bound to previous,current and next Items.  But this does not appear to work.  I've had to make previous, current and nextItems copies of what lives in the allItems array and update those 3 objects at the same time.  Not that big of a deal, but I just would like to, you know, not store copies of objects if I don't have to.  I was hoping there might be a NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty") similiar to C#/Xaml that I missed while going through the API.  This sort of functionality will be most useful to me for future tasks I have on my list due to some of the complexities of our calculated fields and the need to reducing memory consumption as devices get smaller.

Thanks for any help,
~David

Comment: If you need to bind to the change event of a Kendo ViewModel, you can use something like this:

`viewmodel.bind("change", function (e) {
    if (e.field == "currentItem")
        viewmodel.doSomething();
});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever a property of the view model changes, the [change event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observableobject#events-change) is triggered. 
To make this work in calculated fields, you need to access the relevant fields using [ObservableObject.get()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observableobject#methods-get). See [this section](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#important-dependent-methods-must-use-the-get-method-to-get-field-values) in the documentation.

Comment: I should have clarified that I access allItems via self.get("allItems")[currentIndex] already.

I have modified the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem? Or at least show us how you bind the view model?

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle example using kendo and jquery?  I'm not sure how to pull in the external resources there.

Answer (score 3):

2 possible problems.

1) How do you get items into `allitems`?

2) You should also `.get("currentIndex")` since that is the value that you update in `changeCurrentItem`

```
var currentItem = function(){
    return self.get('allItems')[self.get('currentIndex')];
}
```

That should cause `viewModel` to fire its change event for the`currentItem` calculated field whenever `allItems` or `currentIndex` changes.

If all else fails, you can manually fire the change event by doing:

```
viewmodel.trigger("change", { field: "currentItem" });
viewmodel.trigger("change", { field: "previousItem" });
viewmodel.trigger("change", { field: "nextItem" });
```

which would be similar to calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("currentItem")` in XAML.

Comment: Let me try to answer some of the questions posed about my implementation...

1.  I have now changed the code to use: 
var currentItem = function(){
    return self.get('allItems')[self.get('currentIndex')];
}

2.  I decided to try viewmodel.trigger wherever shifting of items occurs.
viewmodel.trigger("change", { field: "nextItem" });

3.  allItems is populated via service calls using self.get("allItems").push(newItem)
--this works for anything bound to the array

4.  The html is bound like this for the various fields:
<div class="warehouse" data-bind="text: previousItem.location"></div>

Comment: Thank you CodingWithSpike... I am using TypeScript and the .get and .set methods were not working for my dependent functions. The viewmodel.trigger approach works like a charm! I also use the same method when using MVVM in WPF.